# What is the purpose of @DBStatus INT OUTPUT and the corresponding SELECT @DBStatus = @@ERROR;?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssms

In the stored procedures of the company I work with,after the set-up commands of USE and SET, and after the CREATE commandI see

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_InsertRespondentSessionSurveyQuotaLifeCycle]
@DBStatus INT OUTPUT, 

...etc etc

 SELECT @DBStatus = @@ERROR
```

What is the purpose of these extra lines? All I know is that I must remove them when I will create new SSRS .rdl reports.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@@ERROR` is a system variable and contains always the latest error from the DB engine.

`@DBStatus` is a variable that stores that value and returns it as output parameter from the stored procedure. That way you can check the error that happened during executing the stored procedure.

Comment: Ah, OK cool - @@ERROR always has the latest error of the DB. Got it, thanks so much!